# Coldfusion Now() Returning The Wrong Minutes

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, date-format

```
DATEFORMAT(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

When using the code above, ColdFusion always returns the time as 12 minutes past the hour. The rest of the date / time is correct, but the MINUTES are always set at 12 past.

- At 2011-12-14 14:02:36.020 returned result is 2011-12-14 14:12:36.020
- At 2011-12-14 13:27:09.783 returned result is 2011-12-14 13:12:09.783

Can anyone explain why? I remember reading something about this in the past, but right now I am pulling a blank.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not now() that's incorrect, it's your formatting. You need to use dateformat() and timeformat() like this:

```
dateFormat(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & timeFormat(now(), "HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

Comment: Just to clarify one point - the OP is seeing 12 because instead of showing minutes, he is showing the month value again.

Answer (score 0):

In Coldfusion, `mm` represents the month instead of minutes. Use `nn` instead of `mm`:

```
DATEFORMAT(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd", "HH:nn:ss.L")
```

Comment: It is worth noting `nn` only works with the [DateTimeFormat](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat) function (CF10+).  As the name implies, DateFormat only works with dates so `nn` is not a valid mask option. Also, it the mask is a single parameter ie no comma in between the date and time masks - `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss.L"`